# How to find own way in data field?

Tags: machine-learning, python, bigdata, sql, databases

I need help finding my path in the data field. I just completed my MSc in Big Data at university. During my studies, I gained approximately Junior level Python and SQL programming skills, worked with the Python Pandas library, worked a little with the R programming language, and used Orange3 a little too. I need to know what exactly I can do with these skills and what would be good to learn more.

Comment: Hi @Gleb, welcome to the site. This site is more oriented toward technical questions rather than career advice, which is very subjective. Your question may be a better fit at other sites like Reddit, which already has [a ton of posts about career advice](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Areddit.com+machinelearning+career+advice), which I suggest you check before posting yet another one.